# The proper way to express a great gratitude in Ukrainian

Tags: вживання-слів, різниця-між-словами, non-native-speaker

What is a proper way to express a great gratitude in Ukrainian?

What I mean here is not something you normally say to a cashier at a shop. For that you would use: *Дякую* or *Спасибі*

I have heard so far:

- *Щиро дякую*
- *Вельми дякую* - seems to be taken from Polish
- *Велике спасибі* - seems to be taken from Russian
- *Дуже дякую*
- *Сердечно дякую* - seems to be taken from German
- *Дякую від усього серця*

EDIT: What I am looking for is a conversational form or direct speech variant. The way you would say it directly to a person you express a gratitude. As per comment - *велика подяка* doesn't seem to be a direct speech to me.

Comment: Всі виглядають нормально, окрім `Велике спасибі` - здається, кращим варіантом є `велика подяка`. Ще є `красно дякую`

Answer (score 12):

Addressing a cashier in a shop seems to be *somewhere between* the official communication and the friends' talk.
So your goal is *somewhere between* the "formal" addressing (long but most accurate) and "rapid speak" (short but rude/sharp sometimes).

> В українській мові найбільш уживаними, стилістично нейтральними висловами подяки є: *дякую* і *спасибі*, які можуть мати при собі **слова, що посилюють вираження вдячності**: *дуже, сердечне, красно сердечно, щиро* та ін. [(source)](http://www.philology.kiev.ua/Lingur/art_93.htm)

So, the answer is, use *дякую* or *спасибі* with any emphasis adjectives/adverbs that are **compact enough**.

Hence, *вельми/дуже/щиро дякую* seems to be fine, while *дякую сердечно/від усього серця* looks like an overhead.

Answer (score 7):

All options are good and are used.

I prefer to say *Щиро дякую* because it is short and sounds very natural in Ukrainian.

I personally dislike *спасибі* because it's very close to Russian *спасибо* so it can confuse the partner especially when I have a dialog with a native Russian-speaking person. As it's mentioned in the comment, *спасибі* is not a transliteration of Russian *спасибо* and has Kyivan Rus Slavic root.

> Два слов’янських слова «спаси боже» в процесі використання злились у
>   цілісність. Сталося це порівняно недавно, у писемних пам’ятках це
>   слово вживається десь з XVI століття поріч із старослов’янським
>   «благодарствую».

[Here](http://www.radiosvoboda.org/a/24821385.html) is more info about *спасибі* and *дякую*.