# Як правильно висловлювати подяку?

Tags: вибір-слова

Поряд зі словом дякую в українській мові використовують спасибі. Чи доцільно його вживати, адже деякі інтернет-джерела позначають  це слово як застаріле чи кальку з російської? І як правильно: красно дякую чи велике спасибі?

Comment: «Спасибі» вживали й Тарас Шевченко, й Леся Українка: http://sum.in.ua/s/spasybi

Comment: Related: https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/246/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Словнику української мови: в 11 томах присутне слово

> **["Спасибі"](http://sum.in.ua/s/spasybi)** ***1. вигук, кому, чому, без додатка і з
>   сполучником що.*** Уживається для вираження, висловлення вдячності за
>   зроблене добро, виявлену увагу і т. ін.; дякую; дякуємо. ***2. у
>   значенні присудкового слова.*** Треба бути вдячним за що-небудь.

В експрес-уроці української мови телепрограми [Сніданок 1+1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P2JyjP_HBek) Олександр Авраменко розповідає:

> "Вдячність можна висловлювати словом **"спасибі"**, яке живе в наших
>   писемних пам’ятках із XVI ст. Воно походить від сполуки слів "спаси,
>   боже". Більш поширеною етикетною формулою висловження вдячності є слово **"дякую"**. Не важливо яке з цих слів виберете ви."
>   Обидва слова вживаються, як рівнозначні.

На сайті [OnlineCorrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D1%8F%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%8E/) радять:

> Замініть нехарактерний для української мови вислів **велике дякую** на
>   стилістично кращий варіант: **красно дякую**