# «Дуже дякую» — правильно?

Tags: сталий-вираз

Натрапив на [статтю](https://vn.depo.ua/ukr/vn/uroki-ukrainskoi-chi-pravilno-duzhe-dyakuvati-i-yak-vimiryati-spasibi-201910021037988) (нижче), авторка котрої не рекомендує вживати словосполучення «дуже дякую». Мотивує тим, що, наприклад, ми не кажемо «дуже бігаю», «дуже пишу» і т. ін.

Але ж є купа дієслів, які вживаються з «дуже»:
«дуже хочу», «дуже поспішаю», «дуже намагаюся», «дуже прошу», «дуже підтримую» і т. д.

Це якраз саме ті слова, які позначають дію, що може мати певну градацію. Саме така дія і «дякувати».

У словниках «дуже дякую» фіксується, та й узус однозначно підтверджує: у живій мові цей вираз застосовується дуже широко. Мовознавець Олександр Авраменко також наводить «дуже дякую» як один із правильних варіантів висловити подяку.

Тож, виходить, що все ж таки можна сказати і «щиро дякую», і «дуже дякую» — різниці немає? Обидва варіанти однозначно правильні в українскьій мові?

Пов'язані питання:

- [The proper way to express a great gratitude in Ukrainian](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/246/)
- [Як правильно висловлювати подяку?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/3077/)

> Нерідко чуємо "дуже дякую". Варіант, скажемо так, не ідеальний. "Дякую" – дієслово. Спробуйте поєднати зі словом "дуже" інші дієслова. Нормально вийде хіба "дуже хочу", "дуже радію" (і ще є кілька слів, але їх небагато). З іншими словами складуться дивні конструкції: "дуже бігаю", "дуже купую", "дуже пишу"… Краще казати "дуже вдячний (вдячна)" або "красно дякую", або просто "дякую". І вже нікуди не годиться "велике дякую" ("велике пишу"? "велике їду"?). Ті, хто кажуть "велике дякую", не замислюються над тим, що "дякую" – дієслово, вони бездумно перекладають тільки його зміст з російського "спасибі", хоча російською "дякую" – це "благодарю". "Очень благодарю" – і в російській мові не кажуть. А "спасибі" є й в українській мові. До речі, і в російській, і в українській сполучення "велике спасибі" і "большое спасибо" – вислови усталені, але чи бездоганні? "Спасибі" означає "спаси Біг (Бог)", тобто людина, якій щось дарують або в чомусь допомагають, у відповідь бажає Божого заступництва, спасіння. А велике оте "спаси" чи маленьке" – як можна визначити? (Втім, цей момент спірний, про це варто й подискутувати).

Comment: Уточніть, в чому полягає ваше запитання. Іншими словами, на яку відповідь ви очікуєте? **Варіант-1:** «Авраменко — авторитет, він має рацію, ось ще 5 посилань на словники, які дозволяють так казати» — годиться? **Варіант-2:** «Пустіва (до речі, хто це?) не знає про існування Авраменка, але все одно має рацію, ось ще десяток маловідомих джерел, які чомусь (всі як один!) порівнюють українську мову з мовськовським єзиком» — годиться? **Варіант-3:** «Пустіва дивується, що "дякую" — дієслово (латиною: *verbium*), а "дуже" — прислівник, латиною (сюрприз!) *ad+verbium*, "при-дієслові"» — годиться?